# iPhone 3GS has color depth of 24-bit color or 18-bit color?

Tags: iphone

I don't understand why Apple did not disclose all the detailed specifications. On apple site, it only tells the most basic specs not all specs so Wikipedia has to search iPhone specs in other sources.

For example, rhe wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone said iPhone 3Gs has 
color depth of 18-bit color while http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3GS said 24-bit color.

Have anyone who did use both 3Gs & 4 or 4s?  Did u see the picture clearer in 4 than in 3GS?

So which color depth does iPhone 3GS have?

24-bit color or 18-bit color?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer, iPhone 3Gs use 24-bit Emulation color not the 24-bit true color.

> 18-bit:  Almost all of the least expensive LCD displays (such as typical
>   twisted nematic types) provide 18-bit color (64 × 64 × 64 = 262,144
>   combinations) to achieve faster color transition times, and use either
>   dithering or frame rate control to approximate 24-bit-per-pixel true
>   color,[12] or throw away 6 bits of color information entirely. More
>   expensive LCD displays (typically IPS) can display 24-bit or greater
>   color depth.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-bit_color#True_color_.2824-bit.29

Note: 18-bit color display was used either dithering or frame rate control to simulate 24 bit (16.76 million colors) per pixel true color; yielding sub-optimal color accuracy and often having poor viewing angles (http://techreport.com/review/23204/tr-summer-2012-system-guide/14)

So correct answer is 24-bit emulation color.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but I could at least try to respond to all **4** of your questions individually.

> Have anyone who did use both 3Gs & 4 or 4s? Did u see the picture
>   clearer in 4 than in 3GS?

You're looking for someone which has been using an iPhone 3GS, 4 and 4s. Please bear in mind that iPhone 4 (and newer) has a retina display and 3GS does not have a retina display. [The iPhone 4 has a 24-bit color.](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2405&view=1&c=apple_iphone_4_a1332_32gb_apple_iphone_3,1)

> So which color depth does iPhone 3GS have?
>
> 24-bit color or 18-bit color?

I don't know what you'd like to know about the color depth, just which one is which? Or what do you want to check?
According to *[this](http://www.mobilesunplugged.com/faq2.php?id=348&faq=67)* site, the iPhone 3GS is 18-bit color.

Comment: Improvements over its predecessor's screen include 24-bit color emulation (18-bit color display plus dithering)[15] for a more color rich display and oleophobic coating to help reduce fingerprints on the display. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3GS)

Comment: so what is the different between 24-bit emulation color and 24-bit color?